# Action Failed on OpenStoredProcedure action in Access Project (ADP) macro

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

In an Access Project (ADP), there is a macro set up the calls a stored procedure on a SQL Server 2005 database (which updates a table, but does not return any results). This macro is called when a user clicks on a button in a form.

It works when logged in as the database owner and the ADP is opened, but when opened by a user with more restrictions, but permissions set to execute, the stored procedure returns with `Action Failed` error, but does not give a reason for the failure.

Macro set up as:

Hourglass   Yes
SetWarnings    No
OpenStoredProcedure dbo.MyStoredProcedure
Requery
SetWarnings Yes
Hourglass No

Comment: what happens if the user runs the SP from the database window?

Comment: Need the macro to run the stored procedure and requery / refresh the form after doing so. It is called after clicking a button on a form.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user does not have privileges on the underlying tables.

Try logging in as the user from SQL Server Managerment Studio and run the Stored Procedure directly.

Comment: The stored procedure worked when running directly (in Access or via Management Studio), just not when the macro calls it.